# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

I am using ASP.Net Identity to create an app with roles based authentication. I want to create some custom roles. When I do that I get the following exception. But I'm unable to figure what's wrong here. Since I'm new to this Please do help me out. Thanks in advance.

I get the exception in
var appRoleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore(context.Get())); 
which is in the ApplicationRoleManager.cs class

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EasyMaintain.SecurityWebAPI
{
    public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
    {

        public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
            : base(roleStore)
        {
        }    

        //create instances for each request
        public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {    

            var appRoleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<AuthContext>()));

            return appRoleManager;
        }
    }
}
```

The RoleModel.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http.Routing;

namespace EasyMaintain.SecurityWebAPI.Models
{
   public class RoleModel
    {
        private UrlHelper _UrlHelper;
        private ApplicationUserManager _AppUserManager;


        public RoleModel(HttpRequestMessage request, ApplicationUserManager appUserManager)
        {
            _UrlHelper = new UrlHelper(request);
            _AppUserManager = appUserManager;
        }
        public RoleReturnModel Create(IdentityRole appRole)
        {
            return new RoleReturnModel
            {
                Url = _UrlHelper.Link("GetRoleById", new { id = appRole.Id }),
                Id = appRole.Id,
                Name = appRole.Name
            };
        }
    }

    public class RoleReturnModel
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

The RoleController.cs

```
using EasyMaintain.SecurityWebAPI.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using static EasyMaintain.SecurityWebAPI.Models.RoleBindingModels;

namespace EasyMaintain.SecurityWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "SuperAdmin")]
    [RoutePrefix("api/roles")]
    public class RolesController : BaseApiController
    {
        // GET api/roles
        [Route("{id:guid}", Name = "GetRoleById")]

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetRole(string Id)
            {
                var role = await this.AppRoleManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);

                if (role != null)
                {
                    return Ok(TheModelFactory.Create(role));
                }
                return NotFound();
            }
        //GET api/roles/5
        [Route("", Name = "GetAllRoles")]

            public IHttpActionResult GetAllRoles()
            {
                var roles = this.AppRoleManager.Roles;

                return Ok(roles);
            }
        // POST api/roles
        [Route("create")]
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(RoleBindingModels model)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }

                var role = new IdentityRole { Name = model.Name };

                var result = await this.AppRoleManager.CreateAsync(role);

                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return GetErrorResult(result);
                }

                Uri locationHeader = new Uri(Url.Link("GetRoleById", new { id = role.Id }));

                return Created(locationHeader, TheModelFactory.Create(role));

            }

            [Route("{id:guid}")]
            public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteRole(string Id)
            {
                var role = await this.AppRoleManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);

                if (role != null)
                {
                    IdentityResult result = await this.AppRoleManager.DeleteAsync(role);
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return GetErrorResult(result);
                    }    
                    return Ok();
                }
                return NotFound();
            }

            [Route("ManageUsersInRole")]
            public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ManageUsersInRole(UsersInRoleModel model)
            {
                var role = await this.AppRoleManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id);

                if (role == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Role does not exist");
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }

                foreach (string user in model.EnrolledUsers)
                {
                    var appUser = await this.AppUserManager.FindByIdAsync(user);

                    if (appUser == null)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("User: {0} does not exists", user));
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (!this.AppUserManager.IsInRole(user, role.Name))
                    {
                        IdentityResult result = await this.AppUserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);

                        if (!result.Succeeded)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("User: {0} could not be added to role", user));
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (string user in model.RemovedUsers)
                {
                    var appUser = await this.AppUserManager.FindByIdAsync(user);

                    if (appUser == null)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("User: {0} does not exists", user));
                        continue;
                    }

                    IdentityResult result = await this.AppUserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, role.Name);

                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("User: {0} could not be removed from role", user));
                    }
                }

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
                return Ok();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that in Startup.Auth, the RoleManager is referenced like this:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Add this reference
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
}
```

Make sure your Controller includes this constructor:

```
private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;
public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager { get { return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>(); } private set { _roleManager = value; } }
```

And make sure you dispose of the Role Manager in your Controller like this:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && RoleManager != null)
    {
        RoleManager.Dispose();
        RoleManager = null;
    }
    if (disposing)
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```